# Register/Login with social media account (i.e Facebook) to magnolia cms

Tags: facebook, google-plus, magnolia

I want to allow public users to register with their Facebook accounts on my magnolia site, for registrations i am using [Public User Registration module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Public+User+Registration+module) how can this be extended to allow users to register/login with facebook or any other social media logins, i.e google+

Anything already available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Social Media Hub](https://wiki.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Social+Media+Hub) does that. It's a pitty that right now only works with Facebook and Twitter.
Ah! And today it doesn't work with the Magnolia 5.4

Comment: Thanks for your answer!